# Determining convergence/divergence of a series

Tags: calculus, analysis

All terms are real numbers.
$$c_0+c_1+\cdots+c_{100}=0,\ c_0\neq0$$
$$a_n=c_0\sqrt{n}+c_1\sqrt{n+1}+\cdots+c_{100}\sqrt{n+100}$$
$$b_n=\sqrt[4]{n^3}$$
The question is to determine convergence/divergence of
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{b_n}.$$
So far I have shown that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent:
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n&=(c_0+c_1\sqrt{2}+\cdots+c_{100}\sqrt{101})+(c_0\sqrt{2}+c_1\sqrt{3}+\cdots+c_{100}\sqrt{102})+\cdots\\
    &=c_0+\sqrt{2}(c_0+c_1)+\sqrt{3}(c_0+c_1+c_2)+\cdots+\sqrt{100}(c_0+c_1+\cdots+c_{99})+\sqrt{101}(c_0+c_1+\cdots+c_{100})+\cdots\\
    &=c_0+\sqrt{2}(c_0+c_1)+\sqrt{3}(c_0+c_1+c_2)+\cdots+\sqrt{100}(c_0+c_1+\cdots+c_{99})+(c_0+c_1+\cdots+c_{100})\sum_{n=101}^\infty\sqrt{n}\\
    &=c_0+\sqrt{2}(c_0+c_1)+\sqrt{3}(c_0+c_1+c_2)+\cdots+\sqrt{100}(c_0+c_1+\cdots+c_{99}).
\end{align*}
but I am lost after this since I cannot apply the direct comparison test.

Edit: The rearrangement above doesn't work by [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)

Comment: You should add your work so far. How did you show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent?

Comment: @Snaw Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you have a misconception about how infinite sums work. Can you spot what the error is? IE How did Bazyli's sequence not converge?

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you. I see that I included false info.

Comment: @BazyliZuczek More like $|a_n| < Cn^{-1/4} $ right?

Comment: @hhs You should leave your work to demonstrate that you've worked on this. Just point out that there's an error (and ideally explain what the misconception is).

Comment: Sorry, it should be $|a_n|\le Cn^{-1/2}.$ Just subtract from $a_n$ the sum of all $c_k$ multiplied by $n^{1/2}.$

Comment: Thank you so much everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. Show that since $b_n = n^{3/4}$, if $|a_n| < C n^{-1/4 - \epsilon}$ for some constant $C$ and $\epsilon > 0$, then the sequence converges.
2. Show that $ |a_n | < ( \frac{1}{2} \sum |c_i| ) ( \sqrt{n+100} - \sqrt{n}) < C n^{-1/2}$ for large enough $n$, and some constant $C$.
3. Hence, the series converges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: In 1, it should be $|a_n| \leq Cn^{-1/4 + \varepsilon}$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. And in 2 it should be $\frac{1}{2} \sum { |c_i|}$ instead of $\max c_i - \min c_i$ (for example you could take $c_0 = -1, c_1 = -1, c_2 = -1, c_{98} = 1, c_{99} = 1, c_{100} = 1$ and the bound written doesn't hold).

Comment: @cha21 Thanks edited. (For 1, it should be $ \epsilon < 0 $ right? )